# What data type(s) can bind to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, datagridview

A `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` allows the value to be one of the members of a list.

I can't figure out what value type this can bind to when binding a `DataGridView` to a custom class. e.g. if I set `DataPropertyName` to "MyProperty" what type(s) may `MyClass.MyProperty` use for getter/setter?

Comment: My tests suggest it merely requires a `string` containing one of the allowed values but I wonder if anyone can point me to documentation supporting (or not) this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be any type as soon as it's convertible **from** `string` (have a proper `TypeConverter`. This also heavily depends on how you set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. The weird thing is when you want to bind to a property of custom class type and just display some property of that class. In such a case, setting just `DisplayMember` does not work and you need to expose some artificial self pointing property of the class in order to bind it as `ValueMember`. I think all that design originates from the old days when you would want to display `obj.Name` but bind `obj.Id`. Anyway, here is a small sample showing what I mean:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var categories = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n => new Category { Name = "Category" + n }).ToList();
            var products = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(n => new Product { Name = "Product" + n, Category = categories[(n - 1) % categories.Count] }).ToList();
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form, AutoGenerateColumns = false };
            dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { DataPropertyName = "Name" });
            var categoryColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = true };
            // data part
            categoryColumn.DataPropertyName = "Category"; // bind to Product.Category property
            // list part
            categoryColumn.DisplayMember = "Name"; // bind to Category.Name property
            categoryColumn.ValueMember = "Self"; // w/o this it doesn't work
            categoryColumn.DataSource = categories;
            dg.Columns.Add(categoryColumn);
            dg.DataSource = products;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Category Self { get { return this; } } 
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```